# Boxes at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

So again I am still pretty new to css/html/javascript and I want to add something like this to the bottom of my site that I saw somewhere and it looked intriguing.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg5LC.png)

If someone can let me know how to even go about doing something like this or even if there is a specific name to it it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much two divs in one big container that are floated next to each other with a background color.

**HTML**

```
<footer>
  <div class="left">
    Right div
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Left div
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Contains the footer */
footer {
  /* Height of the footer */
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.left {
  height: 100%;
  /* How wide they should be */
  width: 70%;
  /* So they are next to each other */
  float: left;
  /* Background color */
  background-color: #7a7a7a;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  /* How high they should be */
  width: 30%;
  /* So they are next to each other */
  float: left;
  /* Background color */
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/y3hzoo08/9/

Comment: I felt like it was something kind of simple. Thanks for the help! Love this site more and more everyday

Comment: one more question, what does the 10em mean under the footer in css

Comment: `em` is a form of measurement, like pixels. See more on [css units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: Change 10em to whatever you want, 10px, 10%, etc it's your height of your footer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like that is as simple as a couple divs at the end of your site.

```
<style>
  #footer {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #272727;
    color: white;
  }
  #box66 {
    display: inherit;
    padding: 4rem 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 66%;

  }
  #box33 {
    display: inherit;
    padding: 4rem 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #171717;
  }
</style>

<div id="footer">
  <div id="box66">
    <!-- 66% width div -->
    Some more content
  </div>
  <div id="box33">
    <!-- 33% width div -->
    Some more content
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jb0pmphu/22/

By far, not an end all be all solution - there are many ways to achieve what that image achieves, but this is one possible solution.

Since you say you're new to this, here are a couple references that I've used in the past.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp